# Associated prime of certain tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, primary-decomposition

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $p\subset A$ a prime ideal. Is $p\otimes_A A/p$ a torsion-free $A/p$-module? The case which I'm interested in is $A:=k[X,Y,Z]/(X^2-YZ)$ and $p:=(x,y)$, where $k$ is a field and $x,y,z$ are the images of $X,Y,Z$ in $A$. I know that the ideal $(x,y,z)$ is associated to the $A$-module $p/p^2$. I want to show that it is not associated to $p\otimes_A A/p$. But I'm not sure whether what I'm trying to prove is correct or not.

Comment: Isn't $Zy=0$, and $y\ne0$ in $p/p^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's why $(X,Y,Z)$ is associated to $p/p^2$.

Comment: I don't understand: doesn't what I said show that $p/p^2$ is not $A/p$-torsion free? And isn't this what you asked?

Comment: No, my question is about the tensor product $p\otimes_A A/p$.

Comment: I've thought that the tensor product is isomorphic to $p/p^2$.

Comment: No, they are not!

Comment: Sorry, I'm making a mistake. They are isomorphic.